# Erlang: print loaded sys.config in OTP application

Tags: erlang

How do I show the *absolute path* that my Erlang OTP application is loading `sys.config` from? I.e., if `get_all_env` (http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_all_env-0) shows unexpected results, how do I see what file is being loaded to debug?

I did this once, so I know it is possible, but sadly I cannot find that code =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [init:get_plain_arguments/0](http://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html#get_plain_arguments-0) to get the full list of VM arguments:

```
(node@localhost)13> init:get_plain_arguments().
  ["/usr/local/bin/rebar3","shell","--apps","some_app",
   "--config","priv/sys.config","--sname","node1@localhost"]
```

That certainly works if you have started the node manually on CLI. For reference, the output above corresponds to my start script using [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/commands#section-shell):

```
rebar3 shell --apps some_app --config priv/sys.config --sname node1@localhost
```

Comment: Yeah unfortunately not quite what I'm looking for because that path is relative (priv/sys.config). I think I have a path problem in Docker so I want the absolute path to the file that was loaded.

Comment: Use file:get_cwd() to get your current working directory. Assuming it hasn't changed, you can use filename:join(Base, Path) with the init argument to build the absolute path to the config file. Also, init:get_argument(config) is easier to use than get_plain_arguments().